# How to use .cargo/config.toml file with both stable and nightly rust toolchain?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have installed both nightly and stable rust toolchains and make some `-Z ...` compile flags for nightly, but the stable rust can't recognize it and stops compiling; is there a way or a cargo directive to conditionally switch between nightly/stable rust compiler.

In .cargo/config.toml file

```
[build]
rustflags = [
"-C...",

"-Z...",
]
```

For nightly rust read `-Z and -C` flags, for stable rust only read `-C` or ignore `-Z` completely. So that, we can use `cargo +stable/+nightly build`  without modify config.toml file every time.

Thanks Ruster ~

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to specify rustc unstable feature inside `config.toml` but you can specify [cargo unstable feature](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/unstable.html). It could be nice to have.

You could create a "nightly" directory:

```sh
cd my_rust_project
mkdir my_nightly_project
cd my_nightly_project
rustup override set nightly
```

Then using [merge feature](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html#hierarchical-structure) of config file of cargo you create you can override the global config using a `my_nightly_project/.cargo/config.toml` file.

Consider using [alias](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html#alias) instead.